# How can I render plain android ProgressBar with Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, android-progressbar, android-jetpack-compose

My application needs a ProgressBar, and I am trying to implement it with Jetpack Compose, so either I need a builtin ProgressBar support (I didn't find it) or there should be a mechanism to display plain Android Widgets with Compose. Is anything of this possible?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Ofcourse, we have Progress Bars in Jetpack Compose:

**CircularProgressIndicator:** Displays progress bar as Circle. It is indeterminate. Themed to Primary color set in styles. Another variant is determinate that takes progress in argument as Float (0.0f - 1.0f)

**Example:**

```
// Indeterminate
CircularProgressIndicator()

// Determinate
CircularProgressIndicator(progress = 0.5f)
```

LinearProgressIndicator: Displays progress bar as line. It is indeterminate. Themed to Primary color set in styles. Another variant is determinate that takes progress in argument as Float (0.0f - 1.0f)

**Example:**

```
// Indeterminate
LinearProgressIndicator()

// Determinate
LinearProgressIndicator(progress = 0.5f)
```

Comment: What is the valid way to modify the progress of indicator? Effect<State<Float>>?

Comment: how to make corners rounded?

Comment: adjusting corner radius on this should be much easier

Comment: @MirzaAhmedBaig doesn't look like it's possible unless you wanna do a bunch of stuff with Shape

Comment: Small comment - the first example has a typo: it is missing an s :D
Thanks for this answer.

Comment: Can you provide an example on how we can call this composable methods from a simple button onClick listener? Because all I get is an error "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function". Thank you!!

Answer (score 23):

With `1.0.x` you can use the [**`LinearProgressIndicator`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#linearprogressindicator) or [**`CircularProgressIndicator`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#circularprogressindicator)

```
// Indeterminate
CircularProgressIndicator()
LinearProgressIndicator()
// Determinate
CircularProgressIndicator(progress = ..)
LinearProgressIndicator(progress = ..)
```

Example:

```
var progress by remember {  mutableStateOf(0.1f) }

LinearProgressIndicator(
    backgroundColor = Color.White,
    progress = progress,
    color = blue700
)
```

To update the value you can use something like:

```
// { if (progress < 1f) progress += 0.1f }
```

[image]

Comment: how to make corners rounded?

Comment: @Mirza Ahmed Baig use app:trackCornerRadius for corner rounded

Comment: how to disappear the ProgressIndicator?

Comment: @Tanjimahmed Just use a boolean: `if (isVisible) { LinearProgressIndicator()} `

Answer (score 5):

For rounded corners we can use this code (It's the same like LinearProgress but with one small correction - in drawLine we use param StrokeCap.Round for rounding)

```
@Composable
fun LinearRoundedProgressIndicator(
    /*@FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0)*/
    progress: Float,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
    backgroundColor: Color = color.copy(alpha = ProgressIndicatorDefaults.IndicatorBackgroundOpacity)
) {
    val linearIndicatorHeight = ProgressIndicatorDefaults.StrokeWidth
    val linearIndicatorWidth = 240.dp
    Canvas(
        modifier
            .progressSemantics(progress)
            .size(linearIndicatorWidth, linearIndicatorHeight)
            .focusable()
    ) {
        val strokeWidth = size.height
        drawRoundedLinearIndicatorBackground(backgroundColor, strokeWidth)
        drawRoundedLinearIndicator(0f, progress, color, strokeWidth)
    }
}

private fun DrawScope.drawRoundedLinearIndicatorBackground(
    color: Color,
    strokeWidth: Float
) = drawRoundedLinearIndicator(0f, 1f, color, strokeWidth)

private fun DrawScope.drawRoundedLinearIndicator(
    startFraction: Float,
    endFraction: Float,
    color: Color,
    strokeWidth: Float
) {
    val width = size.width
    val height = size.height
    // Start drawing from the vertical center of the stroke
    val yOffset = height / 2

    val isLtr = layoutDirection == LayoutDirection.Ltr
    val barStart = (if (isLtr) startFraction else 1f - endFraction) * width
    val barEnd = (if (isLtr) endFraction else 1f - startFraction) * width

    // Progress line
    drawLine(color, Offset(barStart, yOffset), Offset(barEnd, yOffset), strokeWidth, StrokeCap.Round)
}
```

Comment: Make sure you use the import androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas import if you're running into issues.

Answer (score 3):

**custom linear progress indicator**

```
@Composable
fun CustomLinearProgressIndicator(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    progress: Float,
    progressColor: Color = orangeColor,
    backgroundColor: Color = orangeColor.copy(0.24f),
    clipShape: Shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .clip(clipShape)
            .background(backgroundColor)
            .height(8.dp)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(progressColor)
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .fillMaxWidth(progress)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For someone who is looking for a rounded corner linear progress bar,
you can use the Modifier's clip function.

```
    LinearProgressIndicator(
      progress = 0.5f,
      modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp).clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this library which supports thumb, round corners, and animations.
https://github.com/KevinnZou/compose-progressIndicator

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32922877)