# ProgressDialog in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-dialog, android-compose-dialog

I want to show Indeterminate progress dialog when user performs some action like signing up. The old way it was possible using `ProgressDialog`.

For compose, I found this [How can I render plain android ProgressBar with Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59825217/how-can-i-render-plain-android-progressbar-with-compose) But this is not exactly what I'm looking for as it's just a view. It does not cover the screen like dialog does.

With `CircularProgressIndicator` I'm able to achieve this:

[image: compose progressbar]

As you can see it's shown below the views.

I want to create something like this:

[image: expected dialog]

It should have:

1. Dim background
2. draw over other views
3. Non cancellable

How can I achieve this in Jetpack compose?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use the [**`Dialog`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/window/package-summary#Dialog(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.window.DialogProperties,kotlin.Function0)) composable:

```
var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

if (showDialog) {
    Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = { showDialog = false },
        DialogProperties(dismissOnBackPress = false, dismissOnClickOutside = false)
    ) {
        Box(
            contentAlignment= Center,
             modifier = Modifier
                .size(100.dp)
                .background(White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
        ) {
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution works fine, but not on samsung devices with One UI, on them such a dialog is displayed at the bottom of the screen